# T-SQL: How do I flatten out a table like this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table I loaded that looks like this:

```
CUSTID    VALUETYPE    COST
1         A            123
1         B            456
1         C            789
2         B            222
```

And I need to flatten it out in the same table or insert into a new one to look like this:

```
CUSTID      A      B      C
1         123    456    789
2           0    222      0
```

Each row has an identity column not shown.

What would this cursor look like?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `What would this cursor look like?`, do you mean `query`?

Comment: What have you tried???  Have you done any research at all?  There tons of example online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you need to sum the columns:

```
select
  custid,
  max(case when valuetype = 'A' then cost else 0 end) A,
  max(case when valuetype = 'B' then cost else 0 end) B,
  max(case when valuetype = 'C' then cost else 0 end) C
from tablename
group by custid
```

Comment: This one suited my needs the best. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a query, such as conditional aggregation:

```
select custid,
       sum(case when valuetype = 'A' then cost end) as a,
       sum(case when valuetype = 'B' then cost end) as b,
       sum(case when valuetype = 'C' then cost end) as c
from t
group by custid;
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
select custid , sum(case when valuetype='A' then cost else 0 end) A,
           sum(case when valuetype='B' then cost else 0 end) B
,sum(case when valuetype='C' then cost else 0 end) C
from t group by custid
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a PIVOT

```
 SELECT 
    CUSTID
    ,ISNULL(p.A,0) AS A
    ,ISNULL(p.B,0) AS B
    ,ISNULL(p.C,0) AS C
FROM t
PIVOT (
    SUM(COST) FOR VALUETYPE IN ([A],[B],[C])) p
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't mind NULL values in the Results**

```
 Select *
  From  YourTable
  Pivot (sum(Cost) for ValueType in ([A],[B],[C])) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
CUSTID  A       B       C
1       123     456     789
2       NULL    222     NULL
```

**Otherwise, You Can Eliminate NULL Values**

```
 Select *
  From  (Select * From YourTable
         Union All
         Select A.CustID ,B.VALUETYPE,0
          From  (Select Distinct CustID from YourTable) A
          Cross Join (Select Distinct VALUETYPE from YourTable) B
        ) src
  Pivot (sum(Cost) for ValueType in ([A],[B],[C])) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
CUSTID  A    B      C
1       123  456    789
2       0    222    0
```